# Replacing the Slot in an expression

Tags: function-construction, slot

So I've got Mathematica to handle the grunt work for me to obtain expression:

```
Root[ (* blah, blah *) + #^2 + (* etc, etc *)  ]
```

Now, the value inside Root is a polynomial whose all coefficients are at a range of values that Root cannot evaluate symbolically. I actually tried to it forcefully (that is, numerically), but the computer just keeps at it for hours. So I gave up on that.

Anyways, for further processing, I just extract the arguments of Root -- which can be done with function substitution and a some simple text manipulation:

```
sol = (* blah, blah *) + #^2 + (* etc, etc *)
```

Then I want to replace slot # and other slots so I can then apply more operations. And, this is where I get stuck... I don't know how to do it. I've tried:

```
sol & [x]   (* say I want all # to be x *)
```

So how do I do this?

EDIT:
I've editted #3 to #. I really don't know why I didn't do so in the first place, but I soon as I noticed possible misconstrusion, I just panicked.

Comment: The `#3` tells me that you do **not** have a simple `Root[]` object, but a "triangular" one obtained from not finishing the Gröbner basis reduction in full. Why not share the entire thing? Alternatively, you might first want to do a `RootReduce[]` to turn it into a simple `Root[]` object where all the slots are of the form `#1` and the polynomial inside is really the minimal polynomial corresponding to the root.

Comment: Alright, truth is it's #1, but say, if I used that people would think I'm trying to imply I'm number 1. So all I'd get is a lot of disses from other users here. Similarly I couldn't say #2, as it might be misinterpreted as me saying I'm number #2 which is understandably worse without having to explain it here. So actually it's just #1.

Comment: Ignore all comment from here until up.

Comment: That's… not really how we think of slots; the indexing merely refers to the corresponding argument. So, `#3` is a short way to refer to the third argument of a pure function. I don't think anyone here will fault you for using `#1`.

Comment: In any case: have a look at `MinimalPolynomial[]`.

Comment: Sure I might be going at this the crude way (as I'm using function substitution to extract arguments and text to extract left or right hand expressions  -- indicating also that Mathematica should have a stronger type for equalities/inequalities). But, for the sake of answering the question, is there no escape sequence for #? So that one can simply use replacement: % /. # -> x

Comment: The more traditional way to use a `Slot` object is something like `(#^3 - # + 1) &[y]` or `#1^3 - 3#2 &[p, q]`; so, extract the first component of your `Root[]` object and then apply it to an argument.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought I could do... But when I do the simple `sol & [x]`, it won't substitute. I don't know, maybe because it's on several layer of other function calls...  I haven't actually done any thorough looking at it as it would take much time for a newbie like me. First, I'd have to figure out how to trigger an output with a #, #2, #3, etc (as I would not simply type or copy/paste it, as that would be defeating the purpose). Then do more thorough checks here and there... So I just gave up on it and trying to get by with text manipulations.

Answer (score 4):

I *think* this is what you're trying to get at. Say you're solving an equation that generates Root expressions:

```
solution = Solve[x^5 - x^4 + 13 == 0, x]
```

This gives a list of rules with a number of Root expression solutions. Let's just take a look at the first one, for simplicity:

```
firstroot = x /. First[solution] (* gives: Root[13 - #1^4 + #1^5 & , 1, 0] *)
```

Now you want just the first argument of this Root expression:

```
rootfunction = First[firstroot] (* gives: 13 - #1^4 + #1^5 & *)
```

And then you don't want those silly # characters, but something like `x` instead:

```
rootfunction[x] (* gives: 13 - x^4 + x^5 *)
```

---

I think a possible mistake you made is that you put an extra `&` after an expression that is already a pure function, i.e.:

```
rootfunction&[x] (* gives: 13 - #1^4 + #1^5 & *)
```

The reason for this, perhaps unexpected, behavior is that when you have a nested function like `( #1 & ) & [x]` the outer function has no slots (no `#`s) for the `x` to fit into. So the `x` just "disappears" (it's not used in the outer function) and that just leaves the inner function `#1&` to be returned.

Comment: `Root` does work even if the first argument is not a real function though.  This works: `N@Root[13 - #1^4 + #1^5, 1]` (note there's no `&`!).  And even this works: `N@Root[13 - x^4 + x^5, 1]`.  These forms are undocumented and probably a bad idea, but I've seen them used a few times on online forums like this one.  Maybe this has contributed to the confusion.